# MongoDB + ExpressJS - Observe insertions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, observer-pattern

I have a rapidly growing collection in my mongodb. I want to take certain actions when new documents are inserted into those collection. How can I observe and then trigger actions, when such a new model is inserted?

I did discover old solutions such as [mongo-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-observer), but those seem to be pretty old and did not work for me.

Can anybody recommend a relatively new and maintained solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

schema.pre() hooks would do it. Example:

```
export const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: "updated_at" } 
});

schema.pre("save", function (next) {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        this.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

schema.pre("update", function (next) {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        this.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: are there also pre/post hooks for bulk operations on that schema?

Comment: The [pre and post hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) work for every document that is changed, so they would work for bulk operations as well.

If you wanna change something for the whole collection, perhaps you're looking for something like [migrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate)

Comment: I don't need migrate for my case. I am bulk upserting my objects into the database. And each time that one is upserted, I want to trigger another action. Post "save" and "update" and many others are unfortunately not triggered when using bulk.find().upsert().update(), just tried.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer to npm module - [mongohooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongohooks).

**Update:**

Adding sample code:

```
const db = require('mongojs')('mydb', ['members']); // load mongojs as normal 
const mongohooks = require('mongohooks');

// Add a `createdAt` timestamp to all new documents 
mongohooks(db.members).save(function (document, next) {
  document.createdAt = new Date();
  next();
});

// Now just use the reqular mongojs API 
db.members.save({ name: "Thomas" }, function (error, result) {
  console.log("Created %s at %s", result.name, result.createdAt);
});
```